# oracle dwh + workflow/scheduling tool

Tags: oracle

we were using Oracle Workflow Builder for a long time for the plsql packages execution, scheduling the jobs etc. The product is already discontinued so I am looking for some reasonable alternatives. Alternatives as Informatica Workflow scheduler, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Define "reasonable"

Comment: im looking for replacement with the same/extended functionality.

Comment: Some open source schedulers are available and offer the same type of graphs. However, you may have to develop the code in each brick you would like to use.
Can you precise your specifications? Do you need something just to write workflows? Do you need something to deploy them on hybrid clouds? Do you need any specific structure for your workflows? Is there any specific business need that you answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at Oracle Data Integrator and/or Oracle BPEL Process Manager. I think these products are the successors to to Oracle Workflow in the spaces you are looking for.